# Family of Riemannian metrics all equivalent to a fixed metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems, transformation

Consider a smooth ($C^\infty$) manifold $M$ and a family of Riemannian metrics $\{g^{(u)}\}$ on $M$ that depends smoothly on $u\in(a,b)$, in the sense that in certain coordinates $x^i$ on $M$ we can write

$$ g^{(u)} = g_{ij}(u,x)\,\text{d}x^i\text{d}x^j $$

for smooth components functions $g_{ij}$.

Now the situation is as follows. We are given some other metric $h_{ij}(x)$ such that for each fixed $u=u_0$, the metric $g_{ij}(u_0,x)$ can be transformed into $h_{ij}(x)$

My question is if these transformations can be chosen such that they depend smoothly on $u$ as well, i.e., does there exist a family of coordinate transformations $\phi_u:x\mapsto \tilde x$, $u\in (a,b)$ having the property that they transform $g_{ij}(u,x)$ into $h_{ij}(x)$, such that the map

$$ \phi: (u,x)\mapsto (u,\phi_u(x))$$

is smooth, at least locally?

**EDIT**: Let me give an example.

Let

$$g_{ij}(u,x^1,x^2) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\
 0 & f(u)^2\end{pmatrix},\qquad f(u)\neq 0.$$

Clearly, for each $u$, there is a diffeomorphism $\phi_u(x^1,x^2) = (x^1,f(u)x^2)\equiv (y^1,y^2)$ such that in the new coordinates we have

$$\tilde g_{ij}(u,y^1,y^2) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

In this case the diffeomorphism depends smoothly on $u$ as well, in the sense that the map $\phi$, as defined above, now reads $\phi(u,x^1,x^2) = (u,x^1,f(u)x^2)$, which is a smooth function of $u$ provided that $f$ is smooth. In this example everything is very clear, but I'm wondering if such a construction is possible in general.

EDIT: Apparently the result follows from Ebin's slice theorem (see the answer below) but I don't see how. If someone could explain this that would be greatly appreciated. It also seems to me that the slice theory only applies to compact manifolds.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "can be transformed" what you really mean is "isometric to".

A better way to state your question is as follows. Consider a smooth manifold $M$ (this will be a small coordinate neighborhood on your manifold), a smooth family of Riemannian metrics $g_u, u\in (0,1)$, on $M$, which are all isometric to a reference metric $h$. Does there exist a smooth family of isometries $f_u: (M, g_u)\to (M,h)$?

This is nontrivial, but the existence is due to

D. Ebin, The manifold of Riemannian metrics. 1970 Global Analysis (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Vol. XV, Berkeley, Calif., 1968) pp. 11–40, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I.

See Theorem 7.1 in this paper (a slice theorem). It may take you some time to translate from what he proves to what you want since he proves a much stronger result.

Comment: That's great information! Do you also happen to know whether there is a generalization of this theorem to pseudo-Riemannian manifolds? And unfortunately you're right in that it's gonna take me quite a lot of time to apply this to my setting, but in any case this is really useful.

Comment: @Sjorszini: That I do not know. The main issue is that the isometry group of a pseudo-Riemannian is no longer compact which implies that the action of the group of diffeomorphisms on the space of Riemannian metrics is no longer proper.

Comment: How does the result follow from the slice theorem precisely?

Comment: @Sjorszini: Do you realize that the answer was written well over 3 years ago? I would have to take a look at Ebin's paper again.

Comment: I definitely do. Even three years was not long enough for me to figure out how exactly the result follows from the general theorem... ;)